# How to access data file in resource folder in IDE (eclipse)?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am doing the Lambdas and Streams Java 8 tutorial. Instead of adding the data file to the src folder, I created a resources folder in the project and added the data file to it.

Trying to access like this creates a Null Pointer Exception.

```
  private void exercise4() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(
        Paths.get(getClass().getResource(".\\resources\\SonnetI.txt").toURI()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
      /* YOUR CODE HERE */
    }
  }
```

This too, gets same error

```
    Paths.get(getClass().getResource("resources/SonnetI.txt").toURI()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
```

I added resources folder to the build path but same error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at lesson2.Lesson2.exercise4(Lesson2.java:96)
    at lesson2.Lesson2.runExercises(Lesson2.java:42)
    at lesson2.Lesson2.main(Lesson2.java:145)
```

[image: Java build path]

[image: eclipse project structure]

Comment: I think this page [https://howtodoinjava.com/java/io/read-file-from-resources-folder/] has a pretty good tutorial on what you want to achieve.

Comment: To access the file while developing, "/SonnetI.txt" should read the file.  When you create a JAR, good luck.  I have the same problem with reading a txt file.  I can read it in Eclipse, but not when I create the JAR.

Comment: @CodingTil I am using getResource like the link you pointed to. It should have worked.

Comment: @likejudo Yes, you are using `getResource`. However, you are using it quite differently, starting off with your path. How about you give the code in the tutorial a shot and then tell us about your results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the other signatures for Paths and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-) one works!

```
public static Path get(String first,
                       String... more)
Converts a path string, or a sequence of strings that when joined form a path string, to a Path. If more does not specify any elements then the value of the first parameter is the path string to convert. If more specifies one or more elements then each non-empty string, including first, is considered to be a sequence of name elements (see Path) and is joined to form a path string. The details as to how the Strings are joined is provider specific but typically they will be joined using the name-separator as the separator. For example, if the name separator is "/" and getPath("/foo","bar","gus") is invoked, then the path string "/foo/bar/gus" is converted to a Path. A Path representing an empty path is returned if first is the empty string and more does not contain any non-empty strings.
The Path is obtained by invoking the getPath method of the default FileSystem.
```

this works fine...

```
  private void exercise4() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(
        Paths.get("resources","SonnetI.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
      /* YOUR CODE HERE */
    }
  }
```